# invalid content-Length ERROR while uploading 2 GB of stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When Trying to upload 2GB of stream i got invalid content length error
am running Apache as frontend server to mongrel and chrome as my browser.
One more thing one i do it with mongrel alone am able to upload this 2 GB of stream ,cud anybody tell me whats the problem and how do i configure content length in apache??

Comment: You probably want to ask this on server-fault to the apache tag, rather than here to rails.

Comment: yaa but can i post it again under apache tag??

Comment: No. It's a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the problem is that Apache considers it a denial of service attempt and has a cap to prevent you locking up all the server's resources (very reasonable), whether that's configurable or not I'm not sure - can't find anything but will keep hunting. If it's not, you can always build your own copy of Apache with the limit removed.

Have you considered sending the data in reasonable-sized chunks?

You might also wish to inspect the outgoing request using packet inspection or browser debugging tools. It's possible the content-length is being malformed by the browser (I doubt they have a 2GB test case...)

Comment: yaa data is being send chunk by chunk and one more thing i am doing it without apache onle with mongrel(able to upload 6 gb of stream running mongrel alone)....

Comment: So you're not sending 2GB then? You're sending smaller chunks less than that? Streaming it is not the same as sending it in multiple parts. A 2GB streamed HTTP request is still a single request.

Comment: i am sending 4k at a time and when i am trying to upload 2GB FROM CHROME since it only chunke tranfer i got message upload 100% after that error comes

Comment: The packets are being streamed through but it sounds like the actual HTTP request (that those packets form) is large. The server will likely simply not allow a request that large, regardless of how small the constituent packets were. I'd recommend uploading, say, 200MB at a time and then merging the results together at the end manually.

Comment: To elaborate a little:

Assuming your HTTP request is 2GB, your content-length will also be 2GB. It doesn't matter whether you stream the packets, the server is expecting a request 2GB long. It needs to know how long to decide when to end the request. Apache is going to turn around and say 'no thanks' when it sees a content-length that large. Put simply, sending 2GB to a web server is non-standard. There's no situation in which you should have to do it. So a reasonable solution is to send smaller requests, one at a time, then have the server receiving the file put it back together at the end.

Comment: Rushyo i uploaded 1.1 GB of stream ,it looks Apache version issue

Comment: but how do i do that ,means how do mearge these small requests??

Comment: You're sending a file, right?. So split the file up into different parts and turn them into one file at the end using your preferred programming language. If you're not sure how to do that, I recommend starting a new question

Comment: Regarding it being Apache's fault, I recommend you read this before you go filing bug reports: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#id382249

Comment: what does that mean ,can i report erro about apache??

Comment: @AMIT I'm really not convinced. Do you have a link? Just because there's a bug report doesn't mean it's a bug. Half of the bug reports on any major program are nonsense and end up getting ignored.

Comment: Just coming back to this after a while, I thought I'd add a little extra for anyone else reading this. Sending 2GB of data in one HTTP request is plain idiotic. If a server doesn't tell you off, it's not configured right. It is not a problem with Apache, it's a security measure to stop you breaking someone's machine by making ridiculous requests of it. I was being polite at the time but accusing Apache (arguably some of the world's finest coders) of getting something so elementary wrong is utterly arrogant.